# $.ajax returning null data for XML Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, rss

I have a function which loads XML RSS Feed URL http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53dfbdcb7bf94 with this code

```
$(function() {
//      var proxy = 'http://ads.pictela.net/a/hurler.json?feed=';
      var proxy = 'http://ads.pictela.net/a/hurler.json?feed=';
      if(/*proxyRequired*/false) {
        var url = proxy + encodeURIComponent(rssUrl);
        var dataType = 'jsonp';
      } else {
        url = "http://ads.pictela.net/a/hurler.xml?feed=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.contenthub.aol.com%2Fsyndication%2F2.0%2Ffeed%2F53dfbdcb7bf94";
        dataType = 'xml';
      }
      this.loadSettings = {rssUrl:rssUrl, callback:callback, proxyRequired:proxyRequired};
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        timeout: 7000,
        dataType: dataType,
        error: function() {
            console.log("Here");
          if(_this.loadAttempts < 4) {
            if(_this.config['Backup feed file']){
              _this.loadBackupFile(callback, _this.config['Backup feed file'], true);
            } else {
              _this.loadBackupFile(callback, _this.config['Custom feed file'], true);
            }
          }
        },
        **jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        success: function(json) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));**

          if(_this.loadAttempts < 3 && _this.backupLoadAttempted === false) {
            callback(json, _this);
            //console.log(callback);
          } else {
            if(_this.config['Backup feed file']){
              _this.loadBackupFile(callback, _this.config['Backup feed file'], true);
            } else {
              _this.loadBackupFile(callback, _this.config['Custom feed file'], true);
            }
            _this.backupLoadAttempted = true;
          }
        }
```

For code

```
jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success: function(json) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

I get null as the returned rssResponse in IE while it works correctly in other browsers. Please help me figure out why the Ajax GET request for XML Feed Url is not getting processed for IE.

**The issue is the data type:xml is not taken kindly by IE** Can you suggest me ways to get around this.
Thanks and Regards
Swaraj

Comment: Why are you specifying `jsonpCallback` for a non-JSONP request?!

Comment: @Quentin I removed that but still xml data response is not getting retrieved in IE